# Remove duplicated entities from conversation response

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I had the following `@fields` entity:

`innovation` => `change management` (as Synonyms)

When I typed the following in the dialog,

```
show me innovation and change management fields
```

I got the duplicated entities as:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "do.something",
      "confidence": 0.9974480628967286
    }
  ],
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "fields",
      "location": [
        23,
        40
      ],
      "value": "innovation",
      "confidence": 1
    },
    {
      "entity": "fields",
      "location": [
        8,
        18
      ],
      "value": "innovation",
      "confidence": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm expecting to get ONLY one, as I had ONLY one entity with `innovation` or `change management` values. I'm sure no other entities has these two keywords.

Is that a bug! or it's normal behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

In the input `show me innovation and change management fields` there are indeed two occurrences of `@fields` entity. First, the word innovation, which is captured by entity (notice the location index from 8 to 18 character):

```
{
  "entity": "fields",
  "location": [
    8,
    18
  ],
  "value": "innovation",
  "confidence": 1
}
```

Second, `change management`, which is a synonym of `innovation` and that is captured by the entity (notice the location index from 23 to 40 character):

```
{
  "entity": "fields",
  "location": [
    23,
    40
  ],
  "value": "innovation",
  "confidence": 1
}
```

As a value, conversation service always outputs the canonical entity value, which is `innovation` in this case. To get the information about exact literal that was recognized as entity `@fields` value `innovation`, one can type `entity['fields'].get(0).literal` and `entity['fields'].get(1).literal`.

Note that it is a good practice to check the number of recognized entities in the user input beforehand - to avoid accessing non-existent index in the entity array.